# ¿Cómo puedo ubicar las secciones en otro lado de la página?

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando una página de compras donde deseo ubicar las secciones "detalles-compra", "seleccionar-color" y "carrito" en lado derecho de la pantalla. Intenté utilizar display: flex y luego justify-content:flex-end; sin embargo permanecía ahi quieto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
     <section id="prenda">
       <div class="detalles-prenda">
         <h1 class="nombre-prenda">Camisa Blanca</h1>
         <img src="https://centraldesuministrosgs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/camisa-oxford-para-mujer-blanco-central-de-suministros-gs.jpg">
        </div>
      </section>
      
      
      <section id="detalles-compra">
        <div class="tallas">
          <h1>Tallas</h1>
          
          <label class="talla" for="xs">xs</label>
          <input type="radio" id="xs" name="tallas" value="xs">
          
          <label class="talla" for="s">s</label>
          <input type="radio" id="s" name="tallas" value="s">
          
          <label class="talla" for="m">m</label>
          <input type="radio" id="m" name="tallas" value="m">
          
          <label class="talla" for="l">l</label>
          <input type="radio" id="l" name="tallas" value="l">
          
          <h2>Cantidad</h2>
          
             <label for="cantidad"></label>
             <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" min="1" max="4">
           
             <p id="precio"></p>
        </div>
     </section>

    
    <section id="seleccionar-color">
        <div class="color">
          <h1>Colores</h1>

          <button class="negro"></button>
          <button class="piel"></button>
          <button class="azul"></button>
          <button class="naranja"></button>
        
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="carrito"></section>
    <button class="carrito">añadir al carrito</button>
    
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>


    
</html>
```

Aqui el CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&family=Lobster&family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

.detalles-prenda {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

img {
    width: 600px;
}


.talla {
    width: 74px;
    height: 41px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: black;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border: 20px;
}

.negro {
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.piel {
    background-color: darksalmon;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.azul {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.naranja {
    background-color: orangered;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.carrito {
    height: 80px;
    width: 160px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif'
}
```

No sé qué más escribir, pero me pide mas detalles...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">

    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&family=Lobster&family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');

        body {
            font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
            margin: 5% 12%;
        }
        img {
            width: 600px;
        }
        input {
            display: none;
        }
        input:checked + label {
            border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            border: 20px;
        }

        .talla {
            width: 74px;
            height: 41px;
            background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
            font-size: xx-large;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border-color: black;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .negro {
            background-color: black;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .piel {
            background-color: darksalmon;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .azul {
            background-color: blue;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .naranja {
            background-color: orangered;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .carrito {
            height: 80px;
            width: 160px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif'
        }

        .flex { display: flex; }
        .flex-both { justify-content: space-between; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="flex flex-both">
        <section id="prenda">
            <div class="detalles-prenda">
                <h1 class="nombre-prenda">Camisa Blanca</h1>
                <img src="https://centraldesuministrosgs.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/camisa-oxford-para-mujer-blanco-central-de-suministros-gs.jpg">
            </div>

            <button class="carrito">añadir al carrito</button>
        </section>

        <div class="right-content">
            <section id="detalles-compra">
                <div class="tallas">
                    <h1>Tallas</h1>

                    <label class="talla" for="xs">xs</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="xs" name="tallas" value="xs">

                    <label class="talla" for="s">s</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="s" name="tallas" value="s">

                    <label class="talla" for="m">m</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="m" name="tallas" value="m">

                    <label class="talla" for="l">l</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="l" name="tallas" value="l">

                    <h2>Cantidad</h2>

                    <label for="cantidad"></label>
                    <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" min="1" max="4">

                    <p id="precio"></p>
                </div>
            </section>


            <section id="seleccionar-color">
                <div class="color">
                <h1>Colores</h1>

                <button class="negro"></button>
                <button class="piel"></button>
                <button class="azul"></button>
                <button class="naranja"></button>

                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="carrito"></section>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No se si es lo que querías, te añadí dos clases: `.flex` y `.flex-both` y reestructure el HTML, así dentro de un contenedor al que se aplican las clases esta el contenedor cuyo contenido queda a la derecha, y el contenedor cuyo contenido queda a la izquierda.